# CakePHP - Extended Model Associations

Tags: cakephp, model, model-associations

I've very curious about what I'm missing.  Only an example will help explain but here's the sentence question first:  Inventory and InventoryCategory - both have Image associations.  When I view a single InventoryCategory and the related Inventory I would like both Image associations.  Currently I'm only returned the InventoryCategory->Image.  No images are returned for the Inventory items.  This is what I have in the models:

```
Inventory:
 public $belongsTo = 
  array(
     'User' 
   , 'InventoryCategory' 
   , 
  );

 public $hasMany = 
  array(
     'Image' => array
    (
       'className' => 'Media.MediaImage' 
     , 'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key' 
     , 'conditions' => array(
          'Image.model' => 'Inventory' 
        , 'Image.group' => 'Image' 
        , 
       )
     , 'dependent' => true 
     , 'order' => 'Image.rank ASC, Image.id ASC' 
    ) 
   , 
  );

 public function containedModels() 
 {
  $contain = array(
      'Image' 
    , 'User' 
    , 'InventoryCategory' 
    , 
  );
  return $contain;
 }
InventoryCategory
 public $hasOne = 
  array(
    'Image' => array
    (
       'className' => 'Media.MediaImage' 
     , 'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key' 
     , 'conditions' => array(
          'Image.model' => 'InventoryCategory' 
        , 'Image.group' => 'Image' 
        , 
       )
     , 'dependent' => true 
     , 
    ) 
   ,   
  );

 public $hasMany = 
  array(
     'Inventory' 
   , 
  );

 public function containedModels() 
 {
  $contain = array(
      'Image' 
    , 'Inventory' 
    , 
  );
  return $contain;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to pull back both Image relationships within a single find(), then you're going to have problems as CakePHP is only going to select one of those same named relationships, it needs to disambiguate somehow and will either throw an error or just select the first found relationship (which seems to be what you're seeing).

I'd recommend calling the relationships to Media.MediaImage something unique in both cases, e.g. InventoryImage and InventoryCategoryImage rather than just Image.